# Ready API automation framework

Tags: api, automation, soapui, ready-api

This might sound a very vague question, but I am hoping to get some insight from all of you who can throw some ideas so that I can move in the right direction. I have ReadyAPI license and want to develop an automation framework around it. I can of course add assertions and create tests and everything within the tool, but I am wondering if there is a way I can build keyword or data driven framework around it so that I can have reusability, ease of use, adding assertions on the fly, execution via excel, or even adding assertions via excel (not sure). I am not sure if that's going to make creation of tests even more complex. Please provide your valuable inputs!

Comment: Hi, that's an interesting question. I've been around readyapi for some time. It's an interesting tool, easy to use, but for keyword driven or even reuse of restrequests with different data it's not possible

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was wondering if anyone has done anything like that. But while doing my online research, I came across this article which made me rethink: https://www.mindtree.com/sites/default/files/2017-10/102%20mindtree-brochures-web-service-test-automation-framework-wstaf.pdf

Comment: yes, that seems to be a automation framework built around soapui, but with extra complexity (robot framework?? maybe for bdd) around it. I don't think that's a good idea, and there is nothing about that product aside from that website. a solution like that would cause lots of complexity around soapui. I guess that way soapui would be only used for the requests, the rest would be managed by the automation framework. for that I would go for restassured .

Comment: makes sense, then we won't even need ReadyAPI, free soapui would be good enough i suppose. Only difference I see with Robot framework though is that it has inbuilt libraries with keywords around SOAP and REST services which reduces manual effort a bit. But I am still not able to understand why would I create a framework rather than executing test cases from within the tool itself. I know that's exactly I asked in the first place as part of the post, so let's see what conclusion we all come down to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have Ready API! then you probably don't need anything else. The licence is not cheap, so you'd have to consider if you really want to spend *more* money buying something from Mindtree. And, looking at their list of dependencies, there's always the danger of getting bogged down in the tooling and making them work together rather than doing actual work.

Why not start small and simple by doing some [data-driven test cases](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/tutorials/index.html) using Excel or even a database as your source? I've used Excel to drive test cases and to populate assertions and not encountered any problems. For any customised behaviours, there's always Groovy to help. Then, once you've maxed out the capabilities of Ready API! look at something else.

Comment: makes complete sense! Could you please elaborate on how are you using excel for populating assertions and driving test cases? That might actually be what's going to be helpful for my project.

Comment: There's a good tutorial at [Excel Files as Data Sources](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/tutorials/excel/index.html). Each Excel row represents a run of your test case, which gets executed in a loop. The columns are values that get substituted into the steps of your test case. One or more of these columns can be the expected results of the run (pass/fail/specific values), which can be substituted into your assertions.

Comment: For bonus functionality, create a [data sink step step](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/soapui/steps/data-sink.html) to capture to the output of your test case to analyse afterwards.